# webkit-transform translate3d & webkit-overflow-scrolling touch - no click events?

Tags: ios, webkit

I am trying to build a web app, emulating the native iOS UI paradigm of pages swiping left/right.

I have a number of divs stacked horizontally and am using `-webkit-transform` to move between them.

Some of these divs can be longer than the screen height and hence need a scrollbar (while others don't). I don't want a main window scrollbar - I want a separate scrollbar on each div. I am using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` to try to achieve this.

Separately these two declarations work fine, but used together I find that all iPad touch events stop - link & form input clicking doesn't do anything, text selection wont select - the screen is totally locked up apart from scrolling. Works fine on the desktop PC.

Is this a known bug with overflow-scrolling? Seems like a big one. I can set up a jsFiddle demo if necessary. I'm happy to use an alternate method of building this UI if there is one.

Comment: Did you succeed in making a jsFiddle demo? I think that I am having the same issue, but I haven't been able to make a small demo exhibiting the issue.